# Cannot send mail through an internal network,java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-mail

I cannot send an email through an internal network through an exchange mail server.
it gives me this exception

```
    Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: exchange.server, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1961)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
```

Comment: how is configured your firewall ?

Comment: I tried this system variable java.net.preferIPv4Stack but it didn't work

Comment: @ Ayatullah Abdulhakim as your firewall is on, is port 25 open ?

Comment: I think it is a firewall roblem (as you told he is on).

Try to telnet the Exchange server software: In the command window type "TELNET EXCHANGE 25" (use your own server name instead of EXCHANGE,  25 is the port name, please keep that!). The telnet window should open and after a pause of several seconds, the exchange server should answer with something like :

    "220 exchange.YOURDOMAIN.com ESMTP Server (Microsoft Exchange Internet Mail    Service 5.5.2650.21) ready".

It may also comme from your Exchange configuration. Do you have to provide some credentials in order to connect ?

Comment: @ErwanC. how can i know if the port is open or not?

Comment: As i suggested, try to telnet your server.

Comment: It gives me this error "Could not open connection to the host, on port 25: Connect failed"

Comment: Port 25 is used for spam it may come from that. Create an exception in your firewall for port 25. If it isnt enought, try to change your method to use an other port. Configure your exchange server and firewall accordingly.

Comment: I tried on another machine that firewall is off, the mail was sending successfully, Many thanks @ErwanC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an exception in your firewall for port 25. If it isnt enought (Port 25 is used for spam it may come from that), try to change your method to use an other port. Configure your exchange server and firewall accordingly.

Comment: The issue was in firewall, Thanks for support.